# Custom plugin for librdkafka registering oauthbearer_token_refresh_cb not being called

Tags: plugins, apache-kafka, oauth, sasl, librdkafka

I'm trying to write custom plugin for `librdkafka` which will provide custom implementation of `oauthbearer_token_refresh_cb`.

In our company we use kafka with custom OAUTHBEARER sasl mechanism, which is working fine in java/kotlin, also work fine in .Net. Next step is to implement same for `librdkafka` because we need it for Clickhouse DB's implementation of kafka connector which uses `librdkafka`.

I tried with following impelenation for plugin:

#### custom-oauth.c

```
#include <librdkafka/rdkafka.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void oauth_refresh (rd_kafka_t *rk, const char *oauthbearer_config, void *opaque) {
        char err_msg[2048];
        const char *token;
        long long expiry = 0;
        printf("============== Initializing oauthbearer config: %s\n", oauthbearer_config);
        token = "<custom logic implementation>";
        rd_kafka_oauthbearer_set_token(rk, token, expiry, "", NULL, 0, err_msg, sizeof(err_msg));
        printf("============== Oauthbearer token set: %s\n", token);
}

void conf_init(rd_kafka_conf_t *conf, const char *path, char *errstr, size_t errstr_size) {
        printf("============== registering callback\n");
        rd_kafka_conf_set_oauthbearer_token_refresh_cb(conf, oauth_refresh);
        if (rd_kafka_last_error()) {
                printf("============== got some error: %d\n", rd_kafka_last_error());
        }
        printf("============== callback registered\n");
}
```

Compile it with:

```
gcc -c -fPIC custom-oauth.c -o oauth-cb.o
```

Make shared library:

```
gcc -shared oauth-cb.o -lrdkafka -o lib-oauth-cb.so
```

Try it out with `kafkacat` by:

```
kafkacat -L \
    -X debug="all" \
    -X log_level=0 \
    -b my-broker-1:9094 \
    -X security.protocol=SASL_SSL \
    -X ssl.ca.location=/path-to-my-cer.pem \
    -X sasl.mechanisms=OAUTHBEARER \
    -X plugin.library.paths=lib-oauth-cb.so \
    -X sasl.oauthbearer.config="my-custom-oauth-config"
```

Results in:

```
============== registering callback
============== callback registered
% ERROR: No such configuration property: "plugin.library.paths" (plugin lib-oauth-cb.so)
```

If I comment-out all printf-s happening after `rd_kafka_conf_set_oauthbearer_token_refresh_cb` then I don't get `% ERROR: No such configuration property: "plugin.library.paths" (plugin lib-oauth-cb.so)`

But then also doesn't work and my callback for setting oauth bearer token is never called.
This is output:

```
============== registering callback
%7|1605365045.759|SASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Selected provider OAUTHBEARER (builtin) for SASL mechanism OAUTHBEARER
%7|1605365045.759|OPENSSL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Using OpenSSL version OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020 (0x1010107f, librdkafka built with 0x1010107f)
%7|1605365045.762|SSL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Loading CA certificate(s) from file /path-to-my-cer.pem
%7|1605365045.763|WAKEUPFD|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: sasl_ssl://my-broker-1:9094/bootstrap: Enabled low-latency ops queue wake-ups
%7|1605365045.763|BRKMAIN|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Enter main broker thread
%7|1605365045.763|BROKER|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: sasl_ssl://my-broker-1:9094/bootstrap: Added new broker with NodeId -1
%7|1605365045.763|BRKMAIN|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://my-broker-1:9094/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://my-broker-1:9094/bootstrap: Enter main broker thread
%7|1605365045.763|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: sasl_ssl://my-broker-1:9094/bootstrap: Selected for cluster connection: bootstrap servers added (broker has 0 connection attempt(s))
%7|1605365045.763|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://my-broker-1:9094/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://my-broker-1:9094/bootstrap: Received CONNECT op
%7|1605365045.763|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://my-broker-1:9094/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://my-broker-1:9094/bootstrap: Broker changed state INIT -> TRY_CONNECT
%7|1605365045.763|BROADCAST|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://my-broker-1:9094/bootstrap]: Broadcasting state change
%7|1605365045.763|INIT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: librdkafka v1.5.0 (0x10500ff) rdkafka#producer-1 initialized (builtin.features gzip,snappy,ssl,sasl,regex,lz4,sasl_gssapi,sasl_plain,sasl_scram,plugins,zstd,sasl_oauthbearer, CC CXX PKGCONFIG OSXLD LIBDL PLUGINS ZLIB SSL SASL_CYRUS ZSTD HDRHISTOGRAM LZ4_EXT SYSLOG SNAPPY SOCKEM SASL_SCRAM SASL_OAUTHBEARER CRC32C_HW, debug 0xfffff)
%7|1605365045.763|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
%7|1605365046.763|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Cluster connection already in progress: no cluster connection
%7|1605365047.763|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Cluster connection already in progress: no cluster connection
%7|1605365048.763|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Cluster connection already in progress: no cluster connection
%7|1605365049.764|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Cluster connection already in progress: no cluster connection
%7|1605365050.766|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Cluster connection already in progress: no cluster connection
%7|1605365050.766|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
% ERROR: Failed to acquire metadata: Local: Broker transport failure
```

### Notes:

- this kafka cluster has 3 different listeners

  - port 9092 PLAINTEXT protocol (tried kafkacat and it works)
  - port 9093 SSL protocol (tried kafkacat and it works)
  - port 9094 SASL_SSL protocol with OAUTHBEARER as sasl mechanism
- I have installed `librdkafka` and `kafkacat` using `brew` on my Mac and as fas as I can see version of librdkafka is `1.5.0`

## Question

1. Why is my callback `oauth_refresh` never called (no `============== Initializing oauthbearer config`... printed on `stdout`)
2. Why do I get an error `No such configuration property: "plugin.library.paths" (plugin lib-oauth-cb.so)` if there is some `printf` after `rd_kafka_conf_set_oauthbearer_token_refresh_cb`

   - There won't be this error as long as `rd_kafka_conf_set_oauthbearer_token_refresh_cb` is called after `printf`
   - Even multiple times setting does not result in this error:

     - `printf`
     - `rd_kafka_conf_set_oauthbearer_token_refresh_cb`
     - `printf`
     - `rd_kafka_conf_set_oauthbearer_token_refresh_cb`
   - What is the side effect of `printf` to cause this error?
   - This part of question is less important, because I don't plan to keep those printf-s, part `1)` matters

### Goal

- My goal is to have small pluggable lib of our OAUTHBEARER scheme which can be plugged in into anything which uses `librdkafka` (end goal is [Clickhouse](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/kafka/)'s kafka connector)
- I used `kafkacat` just because it's easy tool to experiment with
- Key point is plugability so that there is no need to recompile some app which uses librdkafka just to be able to use custom refresh oauth token logic.

## Edit

I've had several issues:

- signature of conf_init:

  - needs to be: `rd_kafka_resp_err_t conf_init(rd_kafka_conf_t *conf, const char *path, char *errstr, size_t errstr_size)`
  - instead of: `void conf_init(rd_kafka_conf_t *conf, const char *path, char *errstr, size_t errstr_size)`
- when setting oauthbearer token, expiry needs to be `nowMs + someTTL` instead `0` in my example
- I ended up using [rdkafka_example.c](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_example.c)  instead of installed `kafkacat` since latest version of kafka cat that i installed with `brew` was `1.5.0`

  - when running against this older `kafkacat` I was getting following error `kafkacat(76875,0x11b279dc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x10bad7bd0: pointer being freed was not allocated kafkacat(76875,0x11b279dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`
- I got it to work say in consumer mode `-C` but not in print metadata mode `-L` because with `-L` mode does not call `rd_kafka_poll` so my callback was never called.

  - I ended up adding `rd_kafka_poll(rk, 5000);` in [rdkafka_example.c](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_example.c) when `-L` switch is enabled

Comment: That `plugin.library.paths` error indicates that your librdkafka  library was built without plugins support, namely missing `WITH_DLOPEN`. This should be automatically detected on Linux and OSX with the standard `./configure`. Is that what you are using?

Comment: No, I've actually did not compile librdkafka by myself at all, I just installed it precompiled with brew which (among everything elese what brew did) placed `librdkafka/rdkafka.h` in my `/usr/local/include` and I simply did compilation of snippet in question using `gcc` without any kind of extra tools like `make` or `cMake`

Comment: Now I'm thinking... if I need to have librdkafka compiled with plugin support enabled in order to be able to attach some custom plugin that this attaching of custom plugin can only work if application that is using librdkafka is actually using version with plugins enabled. I'm afraid that it wont work for any precopiled application (like kafkacat or ClickhouseDB) if it's shipped precomipled using librdkafka with plugins support disabled. Will I need to build kafkacat (and Clickhouse Db) myself?

Comment: librdkafka will have plugin support enabled on pretty much all modern platforms, so I'm not sure why your build hasn't.  What version of librdkafka?  Also try starting your application and setting the librdkafka property `debug` to `generic`..., it should emit a log line like `... librdkafka v1.6.0-PRE3-32-g134984-dirty-devel-O0 (0x1060000) rdkafka#producer-1 initialized (builtin.features gzip,snappy...,plugins..., GCC... LIBDL PLUGINS ...`.  Check for `plugins` and `PLUGINS` in there.

Comment: well, you can already see this line emitted in output of question `%7|1605365045.763|INIT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: librdkafka v1.5.0 (0x10500ff) rdkafka#producer-1 initialized (builtin.features gzip,snappy,ssl,sasl,regex,lz4,sasl_gssapi,sasl_plain,sasl_scram,plugins,zstd,sasl_oauthbearer, CC CXX PKGCONFIG OSXLD LIBDL PLUGINS ZLIB SSL SASL_CYRUS ZSTD HDRHISTOGRAM LZ4_EXT SYSLOG SNAPPY SOCKEM SASL_SCRAM SASL_OAUTHBEARER CRC32C_HW, debug 0xfffff)`

Comment: I'll also try to clone librdkafaka repo and build it and install

Comment: @Edenhill  I've found the issue causing complain for plugin load. My conf_init()  was returning a `void` instead `rd_kafka_resp_err_t` with value `RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR_NO_ERROR`. That is explaining why randomly placing printf-s resulted in starting vs exiting with an error, becuse something random from call stack was being treated as result of conf_init call